# Laravel Express Js calling

Tags: jquery, node.js, laravel, express

Hi i have a tecnic question i work with laravel but very new with express node, i have my code in jquery to work good, but i need convert in express, i need install express in the folder of my laravel? or i need to install in new folder or where? i actually install express in other folder out of my folder laravel and make call to url of my laravel, but what is the best way? sorry for the redundant explication.

Structure:

```
- api_properties - LARAVEL
    - public
      - js
        - scripts.js - Here is where i have my scripts in jquery.
    - resources
      - views
        - index.blade.php - This is my home page what call the jquery
- apisbproperties - EXPRESS
    - app.js - Here is where i execute the express
```

I need fuse both folders?
I need install express in the folders views of laravel?
I need convert my code jquery to express in my Express folder and call the routes of laravel?

This is my code jquery

```
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

function savePropertiesSB(){
    $.get( "URL_TO_OTHER_PAGE", function( data ) {
        $.post('URL_TO_MY_LARAVEL', {_token : _token, propertiesString: data});
    });
}

function savePropertiesMLS(total_pages){
    var number_page = 0;
    var loaded = 0;
    var url;
    var callSameTime = true;
    var callSameTimeDetail = true;
    while (number_page <= total_pages) {
        url = 'URL_TO_OTHER_PAGE';
        if (callSameTime) {
            $.post(url, function(data) {
                callSameTime = false;
                $(data).find('div.flexmls_connect__sr_result').each(function(){
                    var link_property = $(this).find('.flexmls_connect__sr_address a').attr('href');
                    var property = $(this);
                    if (callSameTimeDetail) {
                        $.post(link_property, function (res) {
                            callSameTimeDetail = false;
                        }).done(function(res){
                            sendData(propertyData(res, property));
                            callSameTimeDetail = true;
                        });
                    }
                });
                callSameTime = true;
            });
            loaded++;
        }
        number_page ++;
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing three very different technologies.

- Laravel - A full blown MVC PHP framework
- Express - A micro framework for Node.js
- jQuery - A [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) library.

So to answer your questions:

> i have my code in jquery to work good, but i need convert in express

You can't just port/convert your jQuery specific code over to Express. Look at your jQuery code. It interacts with the DOM which you can't do in Express because there is no DOM.

> i need install express in the folder of my laravel? or i need to install in new folder or where?

Again, Express is a **micro Web framework**. It is not client side JavaScript code like jQuery.